# I2C device detection on Pi A+

Tags: i2c

Good evening,

I am trying to link a digital thermo sensor ([MR003-001](http://www.tme.eu/gb/Document/a20a3927bd57602269a894d2f5a78012/MR003-001-2.pdf)) to the I2C pins on A+ Pi.
[image]
I have enabled I2C connection in raspi-config, and download I2CdevTools. user is in i2c group, I provided a 3.3V input to the sensor, which can accept between 2.7 and 5.5V. The physical address is 0x48 by default.
[image]
When I am running i2cdetect -y 1, nothing is detected.
I am afraid I may have damaged the sensor (which is brand new).
I have only seen a few topics about I2C integrity checks, and all of them were with devices which had worked at least once before.
I don't really know what to do to make this sensor visible on I2C port, or at least ensure it isn't broken.

Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your setup per se. The datasheet for that sensor board indicates that it has a max current usage of 0.5mA, which is well within the capabilities of the 3.3V supply rail on the Pi. If you wanted to rule out supply current/voltage problems it shouldn't do any harm to try connecting it to the 5V pin on the GPIO header.

Comment: The header pins do not appear to be soldered to the module.  They look like they have just been pushed over.

Comment: I know that, but one thing bothering me was the physical address pin A2 A1 A0. In the datasheet it said the default value was 000, yet just in case I linked them to the ground. Nothing was detected before and after that. A strange thing which occurred while I was trying to wire the A[2:0] pins was the leds on the pi were turning off as soon as I linked the Vcc with one of the A pins. If something was damaged,  it happened there.

Comment: I haven't soldered anything, but the connection is good, all the wires are on the matching line. Do you think the connection is unreliable without soldering?

Comment: I have already tried the 5V pin, before switching to 3.3V pin because I had heard pi GPIO weren't 5V tolerant.

Comment: If you haven't soldered anything the connections are not good. Solder and try again!

Comment: Thank you goobering, i added a bit of tin where it was needed, and this worked like a charm! I feel a bit stupid now, but i though the contact was good enough if I just pressed it against the pins. 
Thanks to all of you too for your attention!